# Maximum overs for a bowler in a reduced over match

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, interruption

In the limited overs cricket match, the overs can be divided between bowlers by maximum 10 per bowler in ODI and 5 in T20.

If an one day match gets interrupted by rain and started after some time by reducing the overs to 40 or 36 or any, what is the maximum no. of overs allowed for a bowler to bowl?

The above scenario is for both the innings or only for second innings.

How will it be for T20I?

Comment: The quota of a bowler in T20 is four overs. Not five overs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, maximum overs allowed per players is decided by dividing total overs by 5. 
E.g. in ODI allowed overs per players = Total overs / 5 = 50/5 = 10 overs. T20I = 20/5 = 4 overs.

Law 12.6 from [ICC's Standard One Day International Match Playing Conditions <sup>PDF</sup>](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/524ac4ae08b48-04%20Standard%20ODI_2013_19%2009%2013.pdf)

> #### Law 12.6 Number of Overs per Bowler
>
> No bowler shall bowl more than 10 overs in an innings.
>
> In a delayed or interrupted match where the overs are reduced for both 
>   teams or for the team bowling second, no bowler may bowl more than 
>   one-fifth of the total overs allowed.
>
> Where the total overs is not divisible by 5, one additional over shall be allowed 
>   to the maximum number per bowler necessary to make up the balance.

So in the interrupted matches, the same formula is used. E.g. suppose an ODI match is reduced to 40 overs then maximum allowed overs per player is 40/5 = 8. Another example: in case the match is reduced to 36 overs then maximum allowed overs per player is 35/5 = 7 and one player can bowl that remaining extra over i.e. total 7 + 1 = 8 overs.

**Edit** (regarding your [another query](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4411/maximum-overs-for-a-bowler-in-a-reduced-over-match/4412?noredirect=1#comment9883_4412)):

> If the match get started with 50 overs per side, after 22 overs gets bowled the match gets interrupted by rain with 4 bowlers used, by sharing 7,7,6,2 overs per bowler. Then the match get restarted with 32 overs per side. Now, how the overs will get divided?

In such situation the same rule is applied. E.g. here maximum overs per bowler is 30/5 = 6 plus any two bowlers can bowl remaining two overs each. I.e. two bowlers can bowl maximum 7 overs and others can bowl 6 overs each. Since <s>two</s> three bowlers have already bowled their quota, they won't be able to bowl further. And captain have to bowl with additional bowler as remaining 10 overs can't be completed with two bowlers when one has already bowled 2 overs.

Comment: If 37 overs means, two bowlers allowed to bowl 8 overs. is it?

Comment: @SportsFan - Yes it is. If 39 then 4 players can bowl 8 overs.

Comment: Same rules for T20I?

Comment: @SportsFan - Yes same rules apply for T20I as well. See [ICC's Standard T20I Match Playing Conditions *PDF*](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/524ac4f092e53-05%20Standard%20T20_2013_19%2009%2013.pdf)

Comment: I have a question regarding the sam topic, if the match get started with 50 overs per side, after 22 overs gets bowled the match gets interrupted by rain with 4 bowlers used, by sharing 7,7,6,2 overs per bowler. Then the match get restarted with 32 overs per side. Now, how the overs will get divided?

Comment: I have one more question for which cant find answer. What if 50 over match gets restricted to 32 over after bowling 21.3 overs and 3 bowlers bowled 10, 9.3, 2 overs. How remaining overs will be divided, and who will finish the remaining over when play resumes?

Comment: @hridayesh: AFAIK, in such case where a 50 overs match is reduced to 32 overs, two bowlers will be able to bowl 7 overs while 3 will be able to bowl 6 overs each. However, since two bowlers have already bowled more than their quota, they won't be able to bowl rest overs. And remaining 10.5 will be distributed between remaining 3 bowlers in similar way of how 32 overs were distributed (i.e. 4,3.3 & 3).